# Sidebar Toggle doesn't work despite of the inline javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a template. While doing so, i encountered a error. I have placed a button that toggles the sidebar from invisible to visible state.I have used the right codes to initiate the jquery response.But the sidebar doesn't toggle.Help me solve this issue

html

```
<a id="click-slide">
<span>
          \
        </span>
</a>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

    $("#posts-container,a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#topbar #category").removeClass("category-list-move")
    });
    $("a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#sidebar").toggleClass("sidebar-move");
        $("#topbar").toggleClass("topbar-move");
        $("#posts-container").toggleClass("posts-container-move")
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

[My site](http://stenzil-demo.blogspot.com)

i have used it with and without Cdata.Where did i go wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your javascript code into document.ready. The reason behind document.ready is you put your javascript code before the a#click-side element. That means when your javascript executed, in the page there is no element called a#click-side. When we put into document.ready it downloads your javascript and all document gently and then starts executing your javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#posts-container,a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#topbar #category").removeClass("category-list-move")
    });
    $("a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#sidebar").toggleClass("sidebar-move");
        $("#topbar").toggleClass("topbar-move");
        $("#posts-container").toggleClass("posts-container-move")
    });
});
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: That's an Absolutely silly answer that changed the way i looked at codes ..Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You've not wrapped your code in a document.ready event handler.  Change it to this...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#posts-container,a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#topbar #category").removeClass("category-list-move")
    });
    $("a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#sidebar").toggleClass("sidebar-move");
        $("#topbar").toggleClass("topbar-move");
        $("#posts-container").toggleClass("posts-container-move")
    });
});
```

It was trying to assign the click event handlers before the page was loaded, so none of the elements actually exist at that time.  Wrapping in the ready handler, as above, means it will only run the script when the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

Added your code when document gets ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#posts-container,a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#topbar #category").removeClass("category-list-move")
    });
    $("a#click-slide").click(function() {
        $("#sidebar").toggleClass("sidebar-move");
        $("#topbar").toggleClass("topbar-move");
        $("#posts-container").toggleClass("posts-container-move")
    });
});
   </script>
```